# i want to print only failed scenarios in cucumber html reports

Tags: cucumber, karate

Is it possible to only print the failed scenario in cucumber-html-reports, i.e if i have 10 scenario out of which 2 got failed, then i want a report of those 2 failed scenarios.

do i have to change anything in dependency in my pom.xml?

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have noticed cucumber html reports, they have 4 different representation of the test results execution,

Based on,

1. Features
2. Tags
3. Steps
4. Failures

If you only want failed report you can use `overview-failures.html` from your report.

Please look for `overview-failures.html` in your `cucumber-html-reports` directory. see if that fits your need.

Comment: Is there a way to just get Failed cucumber steps? I see currently the a report which contains Failed methods(glue code), but not failed steps.